# addEventListener is not working on click

Tags: javascript, menu, material-design, addeventlistener, slidingmenu

Clicking on a button does not seem to do any action,i could not figure out what is wrong.Please help me find the same.

```
 Menu.prototype._initToggleEvents = function() {
    var scope = this;
    this.toggle.addEventListener( "click", function() {
      (scope.menuPosition == "off") ? scope._toggleMenuOn() : scope._toggleMenuOff();
    });
  };
```

Here is the plunker example :
https://plnkr.co/edit/6kd2ZWc1iLJ2q1OPiiIM?p=preview

Comment: your script.js throws Errors

Comment: what is the reason queryselector is unable to find #mm-menu element?and returning always null.

Comment: don't know, and as long as your `script.js` throws errors as soon as it's loaded and executed I would't even try to debug that. Fix your script.js first!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I figured out that triggering the plugin from wrong place was making the addEventListener not being called,moving the script right before the body tag was closed resolved the issue.